# FFmpeg downscale video while maintaining aspect ratio SAR and DAR

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

How can I resize the video (eg 1080x? to 480x?) while maintain aspect ratio (SAR and DAR)?
I want to use the output video to create Dash MPD

I tried multiple filters
`-filter:v 'scale=854:480'`
`-filter:v 'scale=-1:480'`
`-filter:v 'scale=-2:480'`
`-filter:v 'scale=854:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=854:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=sar=1'`

But can get exact SAR and DAR , at least ffmpeg `-f dash` doesn't allow both streams to be in same adaptation set